# How change color index on Flutter. Hallo i want to change color on index with value ''einmal'

Tags: flutter

Hallo i want to change list color on index with value = 'einmal'

Widget _buildChoice() {
return Container(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4,

```
    child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _choices.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return  RaisedButton(
            child: new Text(_choices[index]),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            // 2
            color: _hasBeenPressed ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
            // 3
            onPressed: () => {
              setState(() {
                if(_choices[index] == 'einmal') {
                  _hasBeenPressed = !_hasBeenPressed;
                }
              })
            },
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)
            ),
          );


        }
    )
);}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 color: _choices[index] == 'einmal' ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
```